# float:left; problem in ie6?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6

i have a div with style (`float:left` and `margin-left:10px`).

It working fine in firefox, chrome, safari but in ie it will take extra space from the left side. How to remove that space in ie6 without using hacking.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the [IE Double Margin Float Bug](http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/doubled-margin.html) and you need a hack.

The good news is that it is a valid hack with no side effects.

Set `display: inline`. This will fix the bug but, since the element is floating, not cause the element to display inline.